# Can user flows and custom policies co-exist?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to test out a custom policy but I'm not sure if I'll break my existing user flows if I add a custom policy. **Will adding a custom policy break any existing user flows?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @BradC says, they can co-exist quite happily.

In fact, if you look at a built-in policy and click the "Download" button, you'll see that under the hood it's a custom policy!

What you can't do is mix and match i.e. sign-up with a built-in policy and sign-in with a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

They can co-exist in your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.